# Topological properties of SpecMax(A)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

We consider $A = C_{b}(X)$, the ring of continuous bounded functions on a completely regular space $X$. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\SpecMax}{SpecMax} \SpecMax(A)$ be the set of maximal ideals of $A$ with the Zariski topology.

We know that there is an embedding of topological spaces:
$$ \psi : X \longrightarrow \SpecMax(A) $$
defined by $\psi(x) = m_{x} := \lbrace f\in A \mid f(x)=0\rbrace$.

My question is: We can construct the Stone–Čech compactification of $X$ if we take $\bar{X}:=\overline{\psi(X)}$, but we must prove that $\overline{\psi(X)}$ is compact. We know that $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is quasi-compact, but I don't know if $\SpecMax(A)$ is also. Then how can we prove that $\overline{\psi(X)}$ is compact?

Comment: the base of Zarisky topology is maked by sets $V(I)$ of all promes $p$ containing $I$, for $I$ a subset (or a ideal is you want) of $A$. THen if $Max$-$Spec(A)\subset \cup_i U_i$  for a familiy of open sets $U_i\subset X$, by the definition of Zariski topology above follow that
$X= \cup_i U_i$ (every prime ideals is contained in a maximal one).



Comment: Sergio, the definition of (quasi-)compact requires that every open covering contains a **finite** subcovering. 

Comment: @Ralph, Rajkov ask "how prove that X is quasi-compact?" (then every close of X is quasi-compact too).
  Now from what I write above if $X$ has a open cover, i.e. $X= \cup_i (U_i\cap X)$ for  open sets $U_i\subset Spec(A)$, then  $X\subset \cup_i U_i$ and follow that 
 $Spec(A)\subset \cup_i U_i$ then there are finite collection  $U_1,\ldots U_n$ that cover $Spec(A)$, then cover $X$.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove that $\text{SpecMax}(A)$ is quasi-compact in the same way as you do for $\text{Spec}(A)$. Also note that 
$$\overline{\psi(X)} = \text{SpecMax}(A)=:\beta X.$$
I know of no (very) short proof that $\text{SpecMax}(A)$ is Hausdorff (in Zariski topology). However, a proof is presented in the proof of Theorem 9 (pdf-page 11) in the following well-written paper:

[E. Hewitt: Rings of real-valued continuous Functions. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 64(1948),45-99](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-064-01/S0002-9947-1948-0026239-9/S0002-9947-1948-0026239-9.pdf)

Comment: Hi Ralph. If $R$ is a comutative pm-ring( ring in which any prime ideal contained in unique maximal ideal), then the space of maximal ideals, Max(R), is a Hausdorff space. see "COMMUTATIVE RINGS IN WHICH EVERY PRIME IDEAL
IS CONTAINED IN A UNIQUE MAXIMAL IDEAL, PROCEEDINGS OF THE
AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY
Volume 30, No. 3, November 1971"

Comment: Yes, but I don't think the proof that each prime ideal of $A$ is contained in a unique max. ideal (can be found in Gillman-Jerison), is shorter than a direct proof that SpecMax(A) is Hausdorff. Anyway, the OP should now have enough references to see why the max spectrum is Hausdorff.

Comment: Ok. You are right. But there is a question about the space of minimal prime ideals of a reduced ring $R$. We know that this space is Hausdorff and need not be compact. So it has a compactificaton. Now, what is a compactification of $\mathrm{Min}(R)$, the space of minimal prime ideals of $R$? Note that $\overline{\mathrm{Min}(R)}=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, but $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is not a Hausdorff space.